# SQL query, offset and limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dbconnect

I'm using splunk. Postgres SQL.

I have 2.1M rows to pull up in ASC order.

This is my standard query that is working:

```
WHERE we_student_id = 5678
ORDER BY audit.b_created_date DESC NULLS LAST
```

then I usually use: (if data is more than 1-2M. I split them into batches)

```
FETCH FIRST 500000 ROWS ONLY
OFFSET 500000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 500000 ROWS ONLY
```

this time, my client requested to extract them by ASC order based on audited id not audit_created_date.

I used:

```
WHERE student_id = 5678
ORDER BY audit.audited_id ASC NULLS LAST
```

==========

I tried to pull up the first 500k.

I used:

```
*ORDER BY ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 500000 OFFSET 0*
```

The result is just 100k.

I tried to put maxrows=0 before my select statement with the same query

```
*ORDER BY ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 500000 OFFSET 0*
```

but I'm getting an error: `canceling statement due to user request.`

I tried this query to get the first 400k instead of 500k and removed the OFFSET 0. And I'm still using `maxrows=0` before my select statement

```
*ORDER BY ASC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 400000*
```

There's a result 400k.

When I tried to extract the next 400k, I queried

```
*LIMIT 400000 OFFSET 400000*
```

I encountered the error again: `canceling statement due to user request.`

Usually, I can pull up 2M rows on Database. I usually use "FETCH FIRST 1000000" Then offset the other batch. My usual query on DB is
`ORDER BY DESC NULLS LAST` and use FETCH first and OFFSET

But this time, my client wants to get the data by ASC order.

I tried `FETCH FIRST 400000 ROWS ONLY` query and there's a 400k result. but whenever I increase the number to 500000, I get this error: `canceling statement due to user request.`

I usually use `maxrows=0` because Splunk only shows the first 100k rows. Most of my data are 1-2 Million.

This error only happened when the client requested the reports by ASC order.

I just want to pull up the 2.1M rows on the database and I don't know how to pull it up by ASC order. I don't know if I'm using OFFSET and LIMIT correctly.

Comment: Please don't add tags that are not related to your question. I just fixed it removing the MySQL one. Also please read through this post [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos. Thank you for correcting me. I edited my query. I hope you can help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please format your code too.

Comment: We'd need to see the actual queries, not just part of them.